# Aujourd'hui, les mots régionaux

Tags: régionalismes

Dites-moi, s'il vous plait, comment épeler ce "anw:i"? J'ai aucune idée [image: une carte]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

L'atlas linguistique de la France utilise [l'alphabet Rousselot-Gilliéron](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabet_Rousselot-Gilli%C3%A9ron). La transcription de ces mots en API donne [ɑnɥiː] (avec ī comme au point 328) ou [ɑnɥi] (avec ĭ comme au point 313).

Le mot est équivalent au français à+nuit, et semble couramment épelé anuit ou annuit dans les dictionnaires normands les plus anciens que j'ai consulté ou sur la page wikipédia du [sarthois](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parler_sarthois), mais aussi [ann(h)yi](https://magene.fr/menudico.html), [anieut](https://www.calameo.com/read/000330002d28863d3a558), [anhi ou anhui](https://www.fale-normandie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/Lexique-Cauchois-Didier-Ducastel.pdf) dans des dictionnaires plus récents, qui se calquent moins sur le Français, mais qui reflètent aussi des prononciations plus au nord que sur la capture d'écran dans la question, comme le Cotentin ou le Calvados.

Comment: Merci. Anuit, si simple , mais votre orthographe me confondait